# Why I can't use Math.round in set method C#

Tags: c#, .net

```
private decimal? xposition;
public decimal? XPosition
{
    get
    {
        return this.xposition;
    }
    set
    {
        this.xposition = value;
        Math.Round(this.xposition, 4);
    }
}
```

Why can't I use `Math.round` in set method? It says:

> Argument '#1' cannot convert 'decimal?' expression to type 'double'

Comment: Could you paste up the relevant code inline please?

Comment: private decimal? xposition;

Comment: private decimal? xposition;
  public decimal? XPosition
  {
   get 
   {
    return this.xposition;
   }
   set
   {    
    this.xposition = value;
    Math.Round(this.xposition, 4); 
   } 
  
  }

Comment: You can [edit] your question, rather than trying to add code in the comments.

Comment: Please do not post your code into the comments. Edit your question instead.

Comment: `Math.Round(this.xpositon.value, 4);`

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Assign the value returned from Math.Round to the field: `xposition = Math.Round(value, 4);`

Comment: Right. Now we have a question to answer. Downvote converted to upvote, and voted to reopen.

Answer (score 4):

[`Math.Round`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zy06z30k(v=vs.110).aspx) works with decimal, not nullable decimal. Use `Math.Round(xposition.Value, 4)` instead. Also, note that this value must be assigned to be useful, maybe you meant to do something like:

```
private decimal? xposition;
public decimal? XPosition
{
    get
    {
        return this.xposition;
    }
    set
    {
        this.xposition = value.HasValue ? Math.Round(value.Value, 4) : null;
    }
}
```

Comment: You have an extra semicolon in the setter.

Comment: That is not a problem @vyrp. Not checking for null is.

Comment: Yes, I know. The other answers are more correct. I just wanted to clean the double semicolon. But I can't edit because it would have been less than 6 characters of change.

Comment: @PatrickHofman that's totally right, edited the answer. vyrp I've removed the extra semi column

Answer (score 2):

[`Math.Round`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zy06z30k(v=vs.110).aspx) returns the rounded value, it doesn't modify the value passed. So you have to assign the return value to the backing field `xposition`:

```
xposition = Math.Round(value, 4);
```

But since it's a nullable you have to handle the case that it can be null and you have to cast it to decimal for `Math.Round`:

```
public decimal? XPosition
{
    get
    {
        return this.xposition;
    }

    set
    {
        this.xposition = value == null ? (decimal?)null : Math.Round(value.Value, 4);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues with your code.

- First, you should use the `.Value` of the nullable `decimal`.
- Second, you should check that value if it is `null` before you use it.
- Third, you should assign the outcome.

I would use this code:

```
private decimal? xposition;
public decimal? XPosition
{
    get
    {
        return this.xposition;
    }
    set
    {
        if (value != null)
        {
            this.xposition = Math.Round(value.Value, 4);
        }
        else
        {
            this.xposition = value;
        }
    }
}
```